# Accessing nested hasMany relationship in Ember / Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to access a nested hasMany relationship, expecting the promise. Unfortunately I do not get the expected results with any of the following:

```
// Tried the following
this.get('users.emails')
this.get('users.@each.emails')
this.get('users').get('emails')

// Trying to avoid this:
this.get('users').
  then(function(users) {
    var arr = Ember.A();

    users.forEach(function(user, index){
      arr.pushObject(user.get('emails'));
    });

    return array;
  }).
  then(function(emailArr){
    // then do something
  });

// Preferable
this.get('users.emails').then(function(emails){
  // then do something
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've defined your model with the `async` value set to true like this:

```
users: DS.hasMany('user', {async: true})
```

then typically calling `this.get('users')` will return a promise array, and might not be resolved by the time you actually start using it.

Nested `gets` are tricky, especially with the complication of asynchronous models, so I recommend you do this:

```
this.get('users').then(function(users) {
    users.get('emails').then(function(emails) {
        // do stuff with emails.
    });
}
```

Annoying? Absolutely. Probably necessary? Yeah.

Comment: Hmm ok. Definitely annoying :(

Comment: Yeah, they definitely have some work do to on the async side. Does it work though?